# How to access shared memory type section by Python

Tags: python, mmap, qsharedmemory

I try to make a Python application read data from a shared memory type section. The location of the shared memory is `\Sessions\1\BaseNamedObjects\ObjectName`.

Do I need to use mmap for read this? If yes, how can I open this shared memory? Like `open("\Sessions\1\BaseNamedObjects\ObjectName", "r+b")`?

I tried this, but it reported an invalid argument.

Comment: I tried with fd=os.open('\BasedNamedObjects\ObjectName', os.O_RDONLY) but i have error 'FileNotFoundError'

Comment: Try to escape backslashes `"\\Sessions\\1\\BaseNamedObjects\\ObjectName"`, or use raw string literals `r"\Sessions\1\BaseNamedObjects\ObjectName"`. (`"\1" == "\x01" == chr(1)`)

Comment: I tried with 'r"\Sessions\1\BasedNamedObecjects\ObjectName"' but it's still same..

Comment: Q1, Does "\Sessions\1\BaseNamedObjects\ObjectName" actually exist on your file system? If not you can't open it.

Comment: Q2. If you are using QSharedMemory as tagged, why are you trying to use mmap? This _might_ work in windows, but what created the shared object? A QT application?